# Integer QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a real $m\times n$ matrix and $A=QR$ be the [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) of $A$. For what integer elements of $A$ do $Q$ and $R$ have integer elements?

I think there are two approaches:

1. Constructing $A$ so that $A=QR$. (I think this way is not useful)
2. Constructing an orthogonal matrix $Q$ with integer elements and an upper triangular matrix $R$ with integer elements so that $A=QR$ have integer elements. (I think this way is better, but I don't know how to achieve it)

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea. I want to give an example to the readers of my article about qr decomposition and it will be a nice example if numbers are integer!

Comment: You do realize that $Q$ has to consist of vectors of length $1$, right?

Comment: @DimitarM.H. I'm not sure how you arrived at that. $Q$ can be a permutation matrix. (In fact, permutation matrices are the only possible orthogonal matrices with integer entries.)

Comment: You are right, that was incorrect.

Comment: @Tunococ You are right. I didn't attend to it at all. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every orthogonal matrix with integer entries are of the form $PD$ (or $DP$ if you like) where $P$ is a permutation matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\pm 1$. That means if $A = QR$ and all these matrices have integer entries, then $A = PDR$, and rows of $A$ would be just permuted rows of $R$ with possible sign flips. $A$ must have a certain number of zeros in each column (depending on the column index and its dimension) to guarantee that some row permutation can put it into an upper triangular form.